# Parse HTML Table Values via Angular, NodeJS & Sequelize

Tags: node.js, angular, sequelize.js

I would like to paste HTML source code into an Angular input field, find out a specific HTML table with its ID from the input and store the values of this table in a mysql database using a NodeJS API & sequelize.

My html which i want to proceed:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="mainLayout">
    <head>
    //script
    //script
    </head>
    <body>
    //many html elements, divs, tables etc.
    <table id="table_1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="ra">No.</td>
            <td class="pla">Player</td>
            <td class="res">Result</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="hoverable">
                <tr class="hover">
                    <td class="ra fc">1.&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="pla">random</td>
                    <td class="val lc">12459</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hover">
                    <td class="ra fc">2.&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="pla">random 2</td>
                    <td class="val lc">91526</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="table_2">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="ra">No.</td>
            <td class="pla">Player</td>
            <td class="res">Result</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="hoverable">
                <tr class="hover">
                    <td class="ra fc">1.&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="pla">john doe</td>
                    <td class="val lc">123456789</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hover">
                    <td class="ra fc">2.&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="pla">Jane Doe</td>
                    <td class="val lc">123456</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I process only the table "table_2" from the HTML code above and send it to my database via sequelize?

Comment: this is just a table.  I think you might want to just place input fields on each td and use patchValue to set the values if they are existent.

Comment: hm, i cant place input fields on the td's. i copy some websites quellcode and paste the whole quellcode in one input field. then i have to look for some specific tables, e.g. "table_2" with its element id. like scraping the website but manually

Comment: maybe put this into an ngFor loop then and stringify your pasted code and then just filter it with ngIf

Answer (score 0):

i decided to do the trick in nodeJS with cheerio. to test it, i harcoded my html in string in nodeJS. heres the code which creates the json from the html:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(htmlstring);

const result = $('#table_2 > tbody > tr').map((i, element) => ({
    rank: $(element).find('td:nth-of-type(1)').text().trim()
   ,player: $(element).find('td:nth-of-type(3)').text().trim()
   ,result: $(element).find('td:nth-of-type(4)').text().trim()
  })).get()
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

this logs

```
[
  {
    "rank": "1.",
    "player": "John Doe",
    "result": "123456789"
  },
  {
    "rank": "2.",
    "player": "Jane Doe",
    "result": "123456"
  }
]
```

which i can give to sequelize to continue. now i just have to send my angular input to my nodeJS api, so that i can proceed from there